# aws s3 ls gives error botocore.utils.BadIMDSRequestError: <botocore.awsrequest.AWSRequest object at 0x7f3f6cb44d00>

Tags: amazon-s3

Recently I installed aws cli on a linux machine following the documentation from aws official website. In the first go, I was able to run the s3 commands without any issue. As part of my development, I uninstalled aws-cli and re-installed it. I was getting the error botocore.utils.BadIMDSRequestError: <botocore.awsrequest.AWSRequest object at 0x7f3f6cb44d00>

when I execute aws s3 ls

Answer (score 36):

I figured it out.
I just need to add the region

```
aws configure

AWS Access Key ID [******************RW]:
AWS Secret Access Key [******************7/]:
Default region name [None]: **us-east-1**
```

Then it works!

Thanks.

Comment: ah doh!  thank you. I forgot this as well.