# aws cli returns python objects instead of regular output

Tags: amazon-web-services

I just installed aws cli on Ubuntu following the [oficial installation guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/install-cliv2-linux.html#cliv2-linux-install) on an azure VM.

When I run any command from the command line the results are python objects and not a text or regular output

```
$ aws s3 ls

<botocore.awsrequest.AWSRequest object at 0x7f412f3573a0>
```

I searched everywhere but I cant find any hint.
I already reinstalled aws and also tried using the `output` flag but nothing changes.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This took me a while to figure out as well. For some reason this only affected our CICD jobs, but using the same exact container image and env vars locally worked fine.

Turns out, the issue stems from not providing a region.

You can fix this by specifying the region explicitly in the command:

```
aws s3 ls --region us-west-2
```

Or by providing the region with the available AWS env vars:

```
export AWS_REGION="us-west-2"
# or
export AWS_DEFAULT_REGION="us-west-2"
```

Some related sources that helped me figure this out:

- https://github.com/jwalton/gh-ecr-login/issues/3
- [aws s3 ls gives error botocore.utils.BadIMDSRequestError: <botocore.awsrequest.AWSRequest object at 0x7f3f6cb44d00>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68348222/aws-s3-ls-gives-error-botocore-utils-badimdsrequesterror-botocore-awsrequest-a)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't know how I didn't tried this before, but installing the awscli with apt fixed the issue.

`sudo apt-get install awscli`.

Comment: After having this issue again, I needed to do both, update to latest awscli using apt-get + using the region argument as @tstraley mentioned.